# how to get the list of the lists?

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a problem like that:

```
list = ['a1',['b1',2],['c1',2,3],['d1',2,3,4]]
```

I want to get a new list like that

```
new_list['a1','b1','c1','d1']
```

I do like this:

```
lst = ['a1',['b1',2],['c1',2,3],['d1',2,3,4]]
for item in lst:
   print(item)
```

result is:

```
a1
['b1', 2]
['c1', 2, 3]
['d1', 2, 3, 4]
```

But I want the first element of each result

The best answer is like this :

```
my_list = list()
lst = ['a1',['b1',2],['c1',2,3],['d1',2,3,4]]
for element in lst:
if type(element)==type('string'):
    my_list.append(element)
else:
    my_list.append(element[0])
print(my_list)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first element of list if list is not None: Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327158/get-first-element-of-list-if-list-is-not-none-python)

Comment: Not the same problem

Comment: I think your solution is not right. You want `a1` in output, but your solution prints a single `a` character instead.

Comment: @EbraHim Oh,you are right,I check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as below:

```
>>> my_list = list()
>>> lst = ['a1',['b1',2],['c1',2,3],['d1',2,3,4]]
>>> for element in lst:
    if type(element)==type('string'):
        my_list.append(element)
    else:
        my_list.append(element[0])
```

It will produce:

```
>>> my_list
['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1']
>>>
```

As you see above, first I created a list (named `my_list`) and then checked each elements of your list. If the element was a string, I added it to `my_list` and otherwise (i.e. it is a list) I added the first element of it to `my_list`.

Comment: This won't work because it fails to get a1 as first element

Comment: @karina Thank you. I think it is okay now. :)

Comment: Thank you !I have got some elements when I design a webscraping rule.This. methold help me a lot!

Comment: @championCh I feel like you should be able to find some analog to `car` but maybe not.

Comment: @VermillionAzure all is different for my question.Thanks

Comment: @VermillionAzure May I ask you what do you mean by _Some analog to `car`_, please?

Comment: @EbraHim Some languages might implement Lisp primitives, such as the `car` and `cdr` functions to do list manipulation. I'm more of an R user which does have the two, but I don't think Python has it as a core feature, but I'd imagine it should be somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
res = []
for x in the_list:
    if x is Array:
        res.append(x[0])
    else:
        res.append(x)
```

Comment: It's failed to get the first element of every sub_list.Please check.Thanks